# Customizable flashcard app or site?

Tags: flash-cards

Is there a simple flashcard app or site that lets you import and export a spreadsheet of vocab words and their translations?

I'm trying to find a good flashcard app, but all the ones I'm finding on the app stores require you to manually enter all your words through the app, which is a massive time sink,  and then prevent you from exporting, which locks you into the app, which itself isn't terribly flexible.

Comment: It's easier to just use a dictionary. Also, how is this about language learning per se?

Comment: Anki has this functionality in the desktop version. And then the imported deck is compatible with the mobile apps, at least it was in the past. I think there are a lot of QAs about this already on the site if you look for Anki, Memrise, etc.